# Retrieve table data based on specific condition in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with below data:

```
emp_id | emp_sal | emp_grp

1          5       HMCCR
1         10       HMCPR
1         20       HMCPR
1         30       HMCPR
1         40       HMCRR
2         40       HMCRR
2         50       HMCCR
```

I need to write sql in Teradata where i need to find min(emp_sal) for each group of emp_id.If one or more rows of emp_id has emp_grp='HMCPR' then retain only those rows and take min of emp_sal. Do not do anything when none of the rows have emp_grp='HMCPR' and take min of emp_sal from that group.

Apologize, if you are confused. Based on above condition my output should look like this:

```
emp_id | emp_sal | emp_grp

1         10       HMCPR
2         40       HMCRR
```

I tried below query but it gives min(emp_sal) for each group as i used group by emp_id, emp_grp

```
sel
emp_id,
case when emp_grp='HMCPR' then min(emp_sal)
else min(emp_sal) end emp_sal,  emp_grp

from db_wrk.emp_sin 
group by emp_id, emp_grp
```

Can anyone help me to get expected result in teradata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` with some logic to get the emp_grp HMCPR to be ordered first if it exists.

```
select emp_id,emp_sal,emp_grp 
from (
select e.*, 
row_number() over(partition by emp_id 
                  order by case when emp_grp = 'HMCPR' then 0 else 1 end,emp_sal) as rn
from db_wrk.emp_sin e
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Teradata has a SQL extension, `QUALIFY`, which allows direct filtering on the result of an OLAP funcition (similar to `HAVING`): `select * from db_wrk.emp_sin qualify row_number() over(partition by emp_id 
                  order by case when emp_grp = 'HMCPR' then 0 else 1 end,emp_sal) = 1`